# Errno::EACCES error while using Compass Watch

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, compass, susy-compass

**Background:**
Been using current setup with no troubles while developing a site using Susy gem. Then all of a sudden I get this error. I noticed it after merging a Git branch into my master branch, but I don't think that would have done it, would it? Tried everything including un-installing / reinstalling Compass, Sass, and also tried --pre versions. I'm sill a Noob. I don't even know what the --trace results are showing even though I tried searching.

**Compass** - version 1.0.3
**Sass** - version 3.4.13
**Ruby** - ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295)

**Using a Linux (Arch) machine my PATH is**:
PATH="$(ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir')/bin:$PATH"

**Running compass watch throws error:** 
Errno::EACCES on line ["375"] of /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /srv/http/directory/site/templates/css/style.css

**Directory Permissions:**
.gem directory - drwxrwxrwx 
.SCSS files are chmod 777

**"compass watch --trace" result**

```html
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:375:in `block in clean'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:372:in `each'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:372:in `clean'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:58:in `clean!'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:66:in `prepare_project!'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/watch_project.rb:38:in `perform'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /home/directory/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Problem seems to be about permissions on site/templates/css/style.css. Probably after your git merge you changed the owner for that file. Who owns style.css right now? Is it the same user than the one running compass?

Comment: Thank you so much @yivi! You were absolutely correct! Works like a charm now. 

I wasn't aware Git could change permissions if there is only one user on the machine and branches were all done local.